# Getting error after starting jhipster installation

Tags: jhipster

(14/15) Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
? (15/15) Besides JUnit and Karma, which testing frameworks would you like to use? (Press  to select,  to toggle all,  to inverse selection)
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode in C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\generators\server\templates_README.md while compiling ejs
    at Function (native)
    at Object.Template.compile (C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:495:12)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:306:16)
    at handleCache (C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:169:18)
    at Object.exports.render (C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:332:10)
    at copy.extend.process (C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\mem-fs-editor\lib\actions\copy-tpl.js:12:18)
    at applyProcessingFunc (C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\mem-fs-editor\lib\actions\copy.js:13:16)
    at EditionInterface.exports._copySingle (C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\mem-fs-editor\lib\actions\copy.js:51:16)
    at EditionInterface.exports.copy (C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\mem-fs-editor\lib\actions\copy.js:23:17)
    at EditionInterface.module.exports [as copyTpl] (C:\Users\panka\workspace\Hipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\mem-fs-editor\lib\actions\copy-tpl.js:10:8)

Answer (score 1):

JHipster only supports the latest NodeJS LTS.  Upgrading from v4 to v6 should fix the issue.